# DagNotFound Error when Testing DAG in Airflow CLI

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I’m getting the error: `airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id test_task not found in DagModel` when trying to run a dag via `airflow trigger_dag test_dag`.

DAG is listed correctly when running `airflow list_dags`.  I have also checked to make sure the $AIRFLOW_HOME directory is correctly set to where the dag is.  Only way I can get it to work is by running a specific task such as `airflow test test_dag test_task`. Running `python dags/test_dag.py` shows no errors.

Code in the dag file itself, after imports:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['my@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
  dag_id='test_dag'
  default_args=default_args, 
  schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
)
```

Comment: Ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue before when adding a new DAG (in a new file). Not sure this will help, but basically I think this happens because list_dags causes Airflow to look for the DAGs and list them, but when you 'trigger' the DAG it's telling the scheduler to look for `test_dag` in DAGs *it* knows about - and it may not know about this one (yet) since it's new.

If you have access to the Web UI, you may notice that the DAG doesn't exist when you get this error -- and hitting the DAG refresh button causes the new DAG to show up. I'm sure there's a fancy solution to watch a directory or something and cause this refresh when it changes, but in `airflow.cfg` you can set the refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `dag_id` parameter:

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
)
```

Comment: This still gives me the same error, it looks like the first positional value gets assigned to dag_id anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, it looks like my airflow home env variable was not well set up.

I set it up by doing :

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=$(pwd)
```

And retried and it works...

Answer (score 1):

You can not find DAG in DagModel. I think you should add your dag to the backend (for default it is a file) you can run `airflow scheduler` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your DAG, make sure you're not giving it the Python file. For example, `airflow trigger_dag my_job.py` will produce the error if your `dag_id` is actually `my_job`.

Drop the `.py` part to make it work:

`airflow trigger_dag my_job`

and you may want to make sure that your `dag_id` matches the file name.